# How to add subscript in PlotLegends?

Tags: plotting

When I try to have a X_0=0 in the legend of the plot, I get a reversed order. Can anyone tell me why and how to fix it?

```
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {Subscript["X", 0] "=0"}]
```

One easy way to do this is using the Writing assistant rather than `Subscript`. However, I still don't see how to keep the order I desired, or even more important, how to include different functions/variables in the brackets of `PlotLegends`. For example, what if I wanted to recall a variable value rather than "=0"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you are multiplying a subscript and a string. That is, your input is actually:

```
PlotLegends -> {Times[Subscript["X", 0], "=0"]}
```

and [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times) is [`Orderless`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Orderless), so Mathematica reorders the product into a canonical form. Instead you can use [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row):

```
PlotLegends -> {Row[{Subscript["X", 0], "=0"}]}
```

However, I prefer using [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal) instead, as in:

```
PlotLegends -> {Subscript["X", 0] == 0}
```

so that you rely on the spacing that Mathematica automatically gives typeset expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really convert a subscripted variable to a string, so you should use [`RowBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowBox.html) instead:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {DisplayForm@RowBox[{SubscriptBox["x", "0"], "=0"}]}]
```

You can also use a variable:

```
a = 0;
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {DisplayForm@RowBox[{SubscriptBox["x", "0"], "=", a}]}]
```

Comment: Using `Row` is simpler.

Comment: @CarlWoll could you please show it?

Comment: @CarlWoll very good idea too

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a subscripted variable to a string.

`````
legends = {StringForm["````", Subscript[X, 0]  , "=0"]}
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> legends]
`````

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [MaTeX](http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html) package to include LaTeX typesetting to your plot.

```
<< MaTeX`

texStyle = {FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontSize -> 12};

Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> MaTeX /@ {"x_0=0"}, BaseStyle -> texStyle]
```

[image]